# Textbox validation and other controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

Well i'm pretty new in c# classes and WPF programming.

I make often forms with several textfields and i was wondering if it is possible to make a class to validate the textboxes and other input controls.

Well if i put it in a class i don't have to repeat the code over and over again.

So i validate names on empty and if they are valid text values. An e-mail address is also checked if it is valid and number fields are checked if no letters are written.

Is it possible to do this in a class. Because after the validation you have to return the value.

Some help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Validation class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Validation(v=vs.110).aspx

You can reuse the validation rules across various textboxes, or you could create some custom controls with those validation rules built in (e.g. an EMailAddressTextBox, NumericTextBox, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

---

### Heading

```
<tr>
        <td class="auto-style11" style="color: #FFFFFF">
            Địa chỉ email:</td>
        <td class="style21">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_dcMail" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style15">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_dcMail" ErrorMessage="(7)" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_dcMail" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">(Invalid Email![enter image description here][1])</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code as Tuan Ngo has provided above.

Or you can also create a separate javascript page for validation.

```
function validation() {

var chkTextbox = document.getElementById("textBox1").value; 
var alertMsg = "";

if(chkTextbox==null){
   alertMsg = alertMsg.length > 0 ? alertMsg + "Enter text!":"Enter text!"; 
   textBox1.style.backgroundcolor = "yellow";
   textBox1.focus();
 }
}
```